# Java Code to Get path to installed Firefox on Mac OS x

Tags: java, macos, terminal

I need to find the directory where Firefox Application is installed on Mac, for which i run the terminal command :

```
find / -name Firefox.app 2>/dev/null
```

Now i need to run the same command in a java program, My code is :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class kill{
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
                String cmds[] = {"find","/","-name","Firefox.app"};

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmds);
                p.waitFor();
                //int exitVal = p.waitFor();
                //System.out.println("Process exitValue:" + exitVal);
        BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                p.getInputStream()));
                String line = reader.readLine();
                while (line != null) {
                line = reader.readLine();
                System.out.println(line);
                }
}
}
```

But it does not return me the path. Can anyone tell me what is wrong in here.. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: For starters, running `find` on the whole virtual filesystem can be insanely slow. If you're set on using it, though, you need to post the output of the command-line run, and any `stderr` output you may be getting from your Java application.

Comment: Why don't you do this in pure Java, using something like FileUtils#iterateFiles ?

Comment: Chrylis : It does not display any output. When i uncomment the process exit value it outputs : Process exitValue:127

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a logic error in your loop.  It should be like:

```
String line = reader.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
    line = reader.readLine();
}
```

Although, Firefox should always be in /Applications anyways.